# VK Oauth: Security Error

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, vk

I'm trying to authorize my standalone application. But after I click "Allow" it always redirects to `http://oauth.vk.com/error?err=2` and gives this as response body:

```
{"error":"invalid_request", "error_description":"Security Error"}
```

Here's the request URL (I do have correct `client_id`):

```
https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=...&scope=messages,offline&redirect_uri=https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html&display=page&v=5.37&response_type=token
```

It seems that I've tried everything:

- Turning application on and off
- Passing `scope` as bit mask
- URI encoding some parameters to have correct URL
- and so on

Answer (score 16, accepted):

After hour of searches I've found [this](https://vk.com/topic-17680044_30635058?post=853).

So, it means that user has an old session and must re-login in browser.

Comment: Thanks mate I was sooo frustrated :)

Comment: Thank you, that for about a year, I did not relogin, and never see this error. I never thought that it's helped.

Answer (score 0):

Space in `state` parameter causes this.

[OAuth 2 RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749), sections [4.1.1 on authorization request](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1.1) and [4.1.2 on authorization response](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1.2), recommends using `state` parameter to maintain state in authorization code flow, particularly to prevent CSRF.

When I set this field to `CSRFTOKEN123 http://my.site/next/url`, I got this error. Replacing   (space) with `:` to get `CSRFTOKEN123:http://my.site/next/url` helps.

By the way, I couldn't find any mention of `state` parameter on VK documentation website but VK OAuth 2 authorization system actually supports it. It couldn't be called OAuth 2 otherwise. So I find it legit to use `state` parameter.

The topic https://vk.com/topic-17680044_30635058 mentioned by author is closed now, current discussion is https://vk.com/topic-1_24428376. There are [number of questions on this](https://vk.com/board1?act=search&q=invalid_request%20%22security%20error%22). All in Russian.